# How to convert a portal URL to its corresponding friendly URL

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, friendly-url

I have implemented friendly-url successfully for few of my custom portlets and it is working fine.

When click-able links are generated, it correctly shows the friendly-url.

Now my requirement is that, I need to send this render-URL (say `URL01`) as a parameter (`param02`) to another URL (`URL02`) and this `URL01` then would be displayed on another page.

This is how `URL01` is generated:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="URL01" windowState="<%=WindowState.MAXIMIZED.toString() %>">
    <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
    <portlet:param name="myId" value="<%= String.valueOf(myObject.getMyId()) %>" />
    <portlet:param name="title" value="<%= myObject.getTitle() %>" />
    <portlet:param name="name" value="<%= myObject.getName() %>" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

This is how `URL02` is generated

```
<portlet:renderURL var="URL02" windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>">
    <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
    <portlet:param name="URL01" value="<%=URL01 %>" />
    <portlet:param name="ownerId" value="<%= String.valueOf(ownerId) %>" />
    <portlet:param name="groupId" value="<%= String.valueOf(scopeGroupId) %>" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

This `URL02` would open a pop-up and the `URL01` would be displayed as below in the JSP:

```
URL: <%= ParamUtil.getString(request, "URL01") %>
```

But this shows `URL01` (unfriendly-URL) as:

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/web/guest/mypage?p_p_id=my_WAR_myportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&_my_WAR_myportlet_myId=10989&_my_WAR_myportlet_title=This+is+miine&my_WAR_myportlet_name=What+name
```

If this is a clickable link it generates perfectly as (friendly-URL):

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/web/guest/mypage/-/mine/10989/This+is+miine/What+name/maximized"> Click me! </a>
```

So I need a utility which can convert my unfriendly-url to friendly-URL, something like if a `String` of unfriendly-url is passed - it would convert that to the friendly-url shown above.

Or I have to create an implementation of my own to achieve this?

**Edit:**

```
<route>
    <pattern>/{myId:\d+}/{title:.+}/{name:.+}/{p_p_state}</pattern>        
    <ignored-parameter name="redirect" /> 
    <implicit-parameter name="p_p_id">my_WAR_myportlet</implicit-parameter>
    <implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">0</implicit-parameter>
    <implicit-parameter name="p_p_mode">view</implicit-parameter>
</route>
```

And yes the `URL01` is written above the `URL02` in the JSP.

Comment: Prakash, is URL01 above URL02? If so try using `<liferay-portlet:renderURL />` instead of `<portlet:renderURL />`

Comment: Could you post your file with the URL route mappings?

Comment: @brandizzi Have included the route in the question and @rp yes URL01 is above URL02. Will try with `<liferay-portlet:renderURL />` but can you elaborate what difference it will make?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create your own `<portlet-url-class>` and it will be used when you create the portlet URL with the `<portlet:renderURL>` tag.

In `liferay-portlet.xml`, you can define the `<portlet-url-class>` entry.

If you check the source code of `PortletResponseImpl.java`, the method `createLiferayPortletURL()` checks for the `PortletURLGenerationListener` for that portlet.

I think, you can create a this one and modify URL as you want to.